# Replacement for SPICE 2g6

Tags: spice

I am currently learning the basics of electronics using the website allaboutcircuits.com. I find this site a huge help and I can recommend it to anyone trying to get into electronics. There is only one problem however: the tutorial uses spice 2g6, part because of its simplicity and its help in getting the learner get 'to think like a coder'.

I would love to be able to follow up on the suggestions, but I can't find any working download of sprice 2g6. Does anyone have one, or does anyone know a good replacement that is exactly as educative and simple?

Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I use Micro-cap 11 - you can get a student edition

Answer (score 2):

Try [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net) or - probably easier if you use Windows - [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) (beside the GUI, it can run SPICE netlists).

Answer (score 0):

download it here
http://rhadmin.org/spice/
if for any reason the site is down, use web archive
https://web.archive.org/web/20170313211759/http://rhadmin.org/spice/